# Preciso de um contato igual tem nesses sites de promoção, tipo promoção termina em x dias!

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um contato igual tem nesses sites de promoção, tipo promoção termina em x dias, so que eu quero que quando ele zerar, exemplo: 00:00:00 ele conta 2 dias ( ou 1 dia) pra frente 48:00:00 e começa a contagem regressiva novamente

```
<span id="demo"></span>     


// Set the date we're counting down to
                var countDownDate = new Date("Octo 21 , 2019 19:37:25").getTime();

                // Update the count down every 1 second
                var x = setInterval(function() {

                    // Get todays date and time
                    var now = new Date().getTime();

                    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                    var distance = countDownDate - now;

                    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  days +  " : " + hours + " : "
                        + minutes + " : " + seconds + "";



                    // If the count down is over, write some text
                     if (distance < 0) {
                        clearInterval(x);
                        document.getElementById("demo").data = data + 1;
                    }
```

Comment: Entendi que você esta procurando algo pronto, para apenas acrescentar no seu projeto. Não sei se já fez isto, mas pesquise por **funcao countdown javascript** no google. Você vai encontrar modelos prontos para adaptar a sua necessidade. Para você conseguir fazer que ele espere 2 dias para voltar a exibir a contagem regressiva, você deve guardar a Data/Hora do início da contagem no cache, cookie, arquivo, etc.

Comment: Então eu acho que não precisa guarda a contagem no cache, pois assim que zerar ele vai acrescentar mais 2 dias, ficando 48:00:00, e fazendo a contagem regressiva novamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso da seguinte forma:

Primeiro a variável `countDownDate` deve ser apenas o objeto `new Date` sem a propriedade `.getTime()`, para que ela possa ser alterada posteriormente:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Octo 21 , 2019 11:19:20");
```

Então você declara outra variável pegando o `.getTime()`:

```
var countDownDateTime = countDownDate.getTime();
```

E substitui a variável na linha abaixo, de `countDownDate` para `countDownDateTime`:

```
var distance = countDownDateTime - now;
```

No `if` que detecta quando o tempo se esgotou, você irá acrescentar 48 horas no objeto `countDownDate` e atualizar a variável `countDownDateTime`:

```
if (distance < 0) {
   countDownDate.setHours(countDownDate.getHours()+48);
   countDownDateTime = countDownDate.getTime();
}
```

Assim, se a data do objeto `countDownDate` for `Octo 21 , 2019 11:19:20`, ao adicionar 48 horas, irá ficar com `Octo 23 , 2019 11:19:20`, ou seja, dois dias à frente.

O código irá ficar desta forma:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
 var countDownDate = new Date("Octo 21 , 2019 11:27:15");
 var countDownDateTime = countDownDate.getTime();

 // Update the count down every 1 second
 var x = setInterval(function() {

     // Get todays date and time
     var now = new Date().getTime();

     // Find the distance between now an the count down date
     var distance = countDownDateTime - now;

     // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
     var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
     var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
     var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

     // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  days +  " : " + hours + " : "
         + minutes + " : " + seconds + "";

     // If the count down is over, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
         countDownDate.setHours(countDownDate.getHours()+48);
         countDownDateTime = countDownDate.getTime();
      }
 });
```

Comment: top funcionou certinho1 Muito obrigado

Comment: Que bom. É só marcar a resposta com ✔️. Abs!

Comment: como faço essa marcação

Comment: Do lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo das setas de votação.

Comment: feito, obrigado